# Why is some ordering enforced in generic parameter constraints?

Tags: c#, generics, constraints, language-design

When defining a generic type parameter's constraints, we have to put `class()` at the front and `new()` at the end, for example.

Why is this, why can't I put my constraints in any order?

Are there any other restrictions on ordering besides `class`/`struct` first, `new()` at the end?

---

Example:

```
protected T Clone<T>() where T : class, ICopyable<T>, new()
```

Comment: As background, the language specification lays out that the constraints must be in the order *primary constraint, secondary constraint, constructor constraint*, where a *primary constraint* is simply *class* or *struct*, a *secondary constraint* is a given interface or class type, and the *constructor constraint* is simply the *new()*. As for why they are classified as such and require that order, I have no idea. Perhaps the annotated language specification would shed some light on it?

Comment: Interesting, thanks. It's the why that I'm particularly interested in.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There's no particular reason why that order was chosen. The chosen order goes from more general to more specific, which I suppose is a reasonably nice property.

As for the question "why require an order at all?", it's simply easier on the implementation and testing teams to have a clear, unambiguous order imposed by the language.  We could allow the constraints to come in any order, but what does that buy us?

The longer I work on languages the more I'm of the opinion that every time you give the user a choice, you give them an opportunity to make a bad choice. A basic design principle of C# is that we tell you when things look wrong and force you to make them right -- which is not a basic design principle of, say, JavaScript. Its basic design principle is "muddle on through and try to do what the user meant". By placing more restrictions on what is correct *syntax* in C# we can better ensure that the intended *semantics* are expressed well in the program.

For example, if I were designing a C#-like language today there is no way that I would have ambiguous syntaxes like:

```
class C : X , Y
```

or

```
... where T : X, Y
```

Y is clearly intended to be an interface. Is X? We can't tell syntactically whether X was intended to be an interface or a class. Suffice to say this ambiguity greatly complicates things like detecting cycles in base types vs interfaces and so on. It'd be much easier on all concerned if it were more verbose, as it is in VB.

Comment: +1 Thanks for taking the time to provide some insight into the sort of decisions that get made and why.

Comment: I always found it odd that C# expresses inheritance and implementing interfaces differently than Java (which does it explicitly), when C# is so heavily influenced by Java in most other respects. It's even more odd given that as you say it complicates the compilers work.

Comment: "easier on the implementation and testing teams".. that surprises me.  Even though the implementation of a smaller grammar is probably a bit easier, now you have an entire extra feature to implement and test: "Generate an error when the order is wrong"

Comment: "every time you give the user a choice, you give them an opportunity to make a bad choice.", very true.

Answer (score 1):

Like most syntax related questions, the basic answer is because the spec says so. We get the following grammar for generic type constraints from the C# 5.0 spec (Section 10.1.5)

> *type-parameter-constraints:*
>
> ```
> primary-constraint 
> secondary-constraints
> constructor-constraint 
> primary-constraint   ,   secondary-constraints
> primary-constraint   ,   constructor-constraint 
> secondary-constraints ,   constructor-constraint 
> primary-constraint   ,  secondary-constraints   ,   constructor-constraint
> ```
>
> *primary-constraint:*
>
> ```
> class-type 
> class 
> struct
> ```
>
> *secondary-constraints:*
>
> ```
> interface-type
> type-parameter 
> secondary-constraints   ,   interface-type
> secondary-constraints   ,   type-parameter
> ```
>
> *constructor-constraint:*
>
> ```
> new (   )
> ```

Eric Lippert has done an excellent job of explaining why it was designed this way, so I won't expound on that.