# The 'class' or 'struct' constraint must come before any other constraint. Why?

Tags: c#, generics, type-constraints

Behold the following simple interface:

```
public interface IService { }
```

And now the following open generic class which has a type constraint on that interface and also on any other reference type:

```
public class Service<T>
    where T : IService, class
```

This gives the following error message with red curly lines under the `class` constraint:

> The 'class' or 'struct' constraint must come before any other
>   constraint.

When I *reorder* the constraints like this:

```
public class Service<T>
    where T : class, IService
```

then all is fine.

Now I know this doesn't make any sense, because IService can be omitted if one already uses the `class` constraint. But I am just curious why the order is so important for the compiler?

Comment: Is it actually stopping your project from building? I often have errors like this, but they're more like "suggestions" that don't cause any build errors.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522332/why-is-some-ordering-enforced-in-generic-parameter-constraints

Comment: definitely Ric has answered it with correct link.

Comment: Ah, I did a search myself, but I couldn't come up with those keyword (order**ing**, **enforced**) in my search, rather than the error message itself. Well at least there is a link via the error message now if you search it:)