# Issue trying to combine class type constraint with type constraint for specific interface

Tags: c#, type-constraints

I am trying to write unit tests for a number of "engines". Each engine type has distinct "configurations" but there is significant overlap in how they are instantiated, other arguments, and how the mocks all need to hang together. To solve this, I have a generic test helper class but I am struggling to get the type constraints working how I need.

Following is a simplification that hopefully illustrates the issue:

```
//using Moq;

public interface IGetFooableConfig
{
    int GetFoo();
    // + other things out of scope for this question
}

public interface IFoo1Config : IGetFooableConfig 
{
    // + other things out of scope for this question
}

public class Foo1Config : IFoo1Config
{
    public int GetFoo() { return 1; }
    // + other things out of scope for this question
}

public interface IFoo2Config : IGetFooableConfig
{
    // + other things out of scope for this question
}

public class Foo2Config : IFoo2Config
{
    public int GetFoo() { return 2; }
    // + other things out of scope for this question
}

public abstract class TestBuilder<GetFooableConfigInterface>
    where GetFooableConfigInterface : IGetFooableConfig, class
{
    Mock<GetFooableConfigInterface> configMock = new Mock<GetFooableConfigInterface>();

    public void Bar()
    {
        this.configMock.Setup(s => s.GetFoo()).Returns(1);
        // + other things out of scope for this question
    }

    // + other things out of scope for this question
}

public class Foo1Builder : TestBuilder<IFoo1Config>
{
    // + other things out of scope for this question
}

public class Foo2Builder : TestBuilder<IFoo2Config>
{
    // + other things out of scope for this question
}
```

The Foo1Engine tests then use Foo1Builder, Foo2Engine tests use Foo2Builder (etc x lots)

The issue I am having with the above code is that

```
public abstract class TestBuilder<GetFooableConfigInterface>
    where GetFooableConfigInterface : IGetFooableConfig, class
```

... causes the error

> The 'class', 'struct', 'unmanaged', and 'notnull' constraints cannot
> be combined or duplicated, and must be specified first in the
> constraints list

If I instead change this to:

```
public abstract class TestBuilder<GetFooableConfigInterface>
    where GetFooableConfigInterface : IGetFooableConfig
```

I get a different issue with

```
    Mock<GetFooableConfigInterface> configMock = new Mock<GetFooableConfigInterface>();
```

... that causes the error

> The type 'GetFooableConfigInterface' must be a reference type in order
> to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Mock

This is because Moq declares it as `public class Mock<T> : Mock, IMock<T> where T : class`

If I instead change it to:

```
public abstract class TestBuilder<GetFooableConfigInterface>
    where GetFooableConfigInterface : class
```

This fixes both the above errors but introduces a different issue with

```
this.configMock.Setup(s => s.GetFoo()).Returns(1);
```

... that causes the error

> 'GetFooableConfigInterface' does not contain a definition for 'Foo'
> and no accessible extension method 'Foo' accepting a first argument of
> type 'GetFooableConfigInterface' could be found (are you missing a
> using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can I convince the compiler that GetFooableConfigInterface should be both a class and also an implementer of IGetFooableConfig?

Thanks

Comment: How about specifying `class` as the _first_ constraint? Yes, order matters.

Comment: @Sweeper, ok that works on this simplified example. Let me try on the "real" version and see if it solves there too

Comment: Could you please [edit] question to clarify why you believe fix for "The 'class', 'struct', 'unmanaged', and 'notnull' constraints cannot be combined or duplicated, and **must be specified first** in the constraints list" is to *remove* class constraint instead of moving it to the front?

Comment: I don't believe that. I didn't notice the ordering requirement.

Comment: @Sweeper, that worked great. If you would like to format your post as answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says:

> The 'class' ... constraint ... must be specified first in the constraints list

So you should specify it in this order:

```
public abstract class TestBuilder<GetFooableConfigInterface>
    where GetFooableConfigInterface : class, IGetFooableConfig
{
```

For why this order is imposed, see [Why is some ordering enforced in generic parameter constraints?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8522332/5133585)